# Grafana Prometheus extract label value

Tags: variables, prometheus, prometheus-operator, grafana-dashboard

label: `pv_total{app="example",day="2023_03_15",} 123.0`

Current Grafana dashboard：[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/123j5.png)

The day in my data is redundant, I want to display without it in the data

i hope my dashboard is this(last 7 days, just one line):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXfRN.png)

i don't know how to write query metrics expression to delete the day filed of value

i hava try expression label_replace(), but it's not work,

Comment: Since your counter starts "counting" every day from 0, you would not have a way to create a continuous line like in your desired image. Why are you using such a strange label in your metric, and is there a way to convert it to more traditional counter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use prometheus' `sum()` method, in your case, like this: `sum(pv_total{job="$job"})`.

Comment: While this will result in a single metric - this wouldn't make result graph continuous. Obviously every day metric starts from 0.

Comment: I don't want the data to accumulate, I want my data to be displayed as if there is no day attribute

Comment: Could you show what the graph looks like now?
Every time it starts at 0, the color changes and a different series seems to be started, therefore, summing them together _should_ work right?

Comment: @SIMULATAN The data starts from 0 every time because my daily data will be cleared. I can make it continuous through some functions, but it still has many colored lines